# How can I add a key, value pair on a array of immutable objects?

Tags: immutable.js

I have an array of immutable objects and I want to add a key value pair on all the elements of the array. How can I do this?

Comment: A possible solution it could be converting it to json ...add the property and after that I can convert it back to immutable structure. I am waiting for other solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.map(item => item.set(‘key’, value))